# How can I record screen (gameplay) video capture alongside controller inputs in PS4?

Tags: ps4

I would like to record some of my own gameplay for training purposes. This includes video capture of the screen as well as controller actions during the gameplay (what buttons are pressed and the directions of the thumb pads).

Then I can replay what was recorded (gameplay alongside controller inputs).

Can this be done, and how?

(Pretty sure some professional gamers would do something like that as part of their training?)

Comment: Not sure if this warrants it’s own question but does anyone know if it’s possible to connect to the pc wirelessly while also being simultaneously connected wirelessly to ps4. Basically it’s kind of a drag to be physically plugged into my pc anytime I want to stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [GamepadViewer](https://gamepadviewer.com/) provides what you are looking for.

However, you will need to record your PS4 gameplay footage on your PC using a capture card or something similar. Also you need to connect your gamepad to both your console and your PC by bluetooth binding it to the console and then plugging it into a USB port of your PC.

In your recording program, you can then setup a capture for your browser window, chroma key out the background and layer it on top of your footage. If there is some input lag, you can adjust the delay using in-url settings, e.g.

```
https://gamepadviewer.com/?delay=2000
```

This is and more settings are explained on the info page of the tool. You can also change the skin of the controller to PS4 (black or white) or remap the buttons (e.g. if you changed the mapping through accessibility settings of your PS4). There even is a URL-generator that let's you pick all your options very easily.

I tested this on my PS4 Pro and Chrome under Windows 10 Pro and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out, looks like just what I need. Don't think I need to capture gameplay footage via a PC capture card though. I suppose I can record it separately on the PS4, and then overlay the 2 videos later.

Comment: Definitely! Think about a way to sync both captures. Maybe a certain rhythmic button sequence that you will easily recognize to match them together.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the PS4 Camera aimed at your DS4.  If setup up correctly the PS4 will stream the game with your controller in the picture-n-picture instead of your beautiful mug.